# How to match a backslash in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to figure out wheather a string contains two slashes. The forward slash is easy to check

```
String test = "12/13/2013";
boolean slash = test.matches("\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+");
```

---

But how to check for a **back slash** ?

```
String test = "12\13\2013";
boolean slash = test.matches("\\d+\\\\\\d+\\\\\\d+");
```

The above does not recognize it ? I also tried `("\\d+\\\\d+\\\\d+")`

Comment: This ``\`` is a backslash, and this `/` is a forward slash.

Comment: `"12\13\2013"` -> `"12\\13\\2013"`. You need to escape \ in all literals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You escaped your regex properly, but you didn't escape your test string properly.  Try

```
String test = "12\\13\\2013";
```

Interestingly, your code `String test = "12\13\2013";` does compile, because you inadvertently specified characters by their *octal escapes*, which are specified by a backslash followed by an octal number, from `\000` through `\377`.  I.e. `\13` and `\201` are octal escapes.